# Plotly plot single trace with 2 yaxis

Tags: python, plotly

I have a plotly graph object bar chart for which I want to display 2 y-axis (different currencies, so the conversion factor ist constant).

Currently I plot 1 trace each, while for the second one I set opacity to 0, disable the legend and hoverinfo. This hack works, but is ugly to maintain.

I'm aware of https://plotly.com/python/multiple-axes/

my current solution looks like this

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# make up some data
dates = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('1/1/2023','1/7/2023'), columns=['date'])
dates["key"] = 0
items = pd.DataFrame(["A","B","C"], columns=['items'])
items["key"] = 0
df = dates.merge(items,on="key",how="outer").drop("key",axis=1)
df['price_USD'] = np.random.randint(0, 100, df.shape[0])
df['price_EURO'] = df['price_USD']/1.5

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])  
for item, _df in df.groupby("items",sort=True):
    ## we may set the colors of the individual items manually here
    fig.add_trace(
                go.Bar(
                    x=_df["date"],
                    y=_df["price_USD"],
                    showlegend=True,
                    name=item,
                    opacity=1.0,
                    #color=color,
                    legendgroup=item

                ),
                secondary_y=False,
            )

    # invisible trace
    fig.add_trace(
                go.Bar(
                    x=_df["date"],
                    y=_df["price_EURO"],
                    showlegend=False,
                    opacity=0.0,
                    name="",
                    hoverinfo="skip",
                    legendgroup=item
                ),
                secondary_y=True,
            )

fig.update_layout(barmode="stack")
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="<b>Cost USD", secondary_y=False)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="<b>Cost Euro", showgrid=False, secondary_y=True)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and current code before you consider it a hassle? Guess data and guess code may not be able to capture your intention.

Comment: @r-beginners I included a self-contained example of my current approach

Answer (score 5):

One can use the other side as a `scaleanchor` and provide the scaling. Doubling the data is then not necessary anymore.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
np.random.seed(1)

RATIO = 1.5

# make up some data
dates = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('1/1/2023','1/7/2023'), columns=['date'])
dates["key"] = 0
items = pd.DataFrame(["A","B","C"], columns=['items'])
items["key"] = 0
df = dates.merge(items,on="key",how="outer").drop("key",axis=1)
df['price_USD'] = np.random.randint(0, 100, df.shape[0])

# This is not needed more, at least for displaying it
#df['price_EURO'] = df['price_USD']/ RATIO

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])  
for item, _df in df.groupby("items",sort=True):
    ## we may set the colors of the individual items manually here
    fig.add_trace(
                go.Bar(
                    x=_df["date"],
                    y=_df["price_USD"],
                    showlegend=True,
                    name=item,
                    opacity=1.0,
                    #color=color,
                    legendgroup=item

                ),
                secondary_y=False,

            )
 
# Add a dummy trace to activate the second axis  
fig.add_trace(
            go.Bar(visible=False),
            secondary_y=True,
        )
fig.update_layout(barmode="stack")
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="<b>Cost USD", secondary_y=False)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="<b>Cost Euro", showgrid=False, secondary_y=True)
# Set scale according to the other axis and the defined ratio
# the constraint assures that it is bottom aligned
fig.update_layout(yaxis2=dict(scaleanchor="y1", scaleratio=RATIO, constraintoward="bottom"))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: First thought it works, but it showes a strange behavior if only 1 item (e.g. B) is selected by double-click on the legend. In this case, the y-axis RATIO is broken

Comment: The scaleratio remains correct when you do that, you just need to apply `constraintoward='bottom'` to yaxis as well in order to keep them aligned.

Comment: @EricLavault Good point! But the automatic rescaling of the y-axis is disabled then (range stays constant which may causes the need for manual zooming)

Comment: @EricLavault even with `fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(constraintoward="bottom"))`, there are problems with zooming (right y axis can get negative while left one is still positive)

Comment: I am a bit confused as it sometimes syncs the axes correctly when interacting with it, but cannot get it right in 100% of the cases.

Comment: "_But the automatic rescaling of the y-axis is disabled then_", it seems to be the case already without `constraintoward="bottom"`, I think this is rather a consequence of having a trace without any data : when resetting scale (doubleclick in zoom mode or via the autoscale button) the zoom range is correctly reset for y but not for y2, it just doesn't change, but when you zoom in/out manually (before reset at least) it works because of the scale anchor.

Comment: I you really need to enable zooming you could add some javascript to override the range of y2 on relayout when necessary.

Comment: `matches` allows to sync the axes perfectly but cannot be used with `scaleanchor`. One could use a categorical axes (and customized zoom levels) with the scaled values as customized tick text but underlying the same values. This would be a bit of a hassle. Further. depending on how fine grained the zoom levels are and the absolute range might not scale well (e.g. if 1M in 1$ steps, need 1M categorical values)